# Enable button on jsp after navigating to it through a href from source page

Tags: html, jsp

I call a JSP at the time of server operations and get the display of all I need.
Now, I have a special scenario where I shall call the page by clicking on a link using a href from other JSP.
When I navigate to my JSP by clicking the link, I want a button enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Pass additional parameter by `<a href="some.jsp?enable=false">link</a>`. In jsp check for the parameter and set the button state as disabled.

```
<button <%=("false".equals(request.getPrameter("enable"))?"disabled":""%> > OK </button>
```